# Less number of king stud

Tags: framing

This is stair tall wall 19' high. as per design around door there should be one jack and two king studs, contractor installed only one king stud on right side of door as there is another partition wall(immediate after the king stud) perpendicular to tall wall. Is there any solution without removing any member?
please advise[image]

Comment: Solution to what? You haven't made the problem clear.

Comment: Why are 2 king studs required on each side of door? Is there a note referring to this requirement?

Comment: are you sure there's only one king stud on the right?  the stud on the right wall is blocking my view.  does that stud not count?

Comment: On right side There is one jack stud under the lintel beam and one king stud

Comment: As per design there should be two king studs and one jack stud